# How to know which child view is clicked in a relativelayout

Tags: android, view, android-relativelayout

I have a relative layout to which child views are added  and removed dynamically(any number can be added or removed)

My question is how to know which view was clicked so that i can add different onclicklisteners depending on the type of child views

Comment: while adding and removing set unique ids or tags, and set common onclick listener(activity implementing best approch). In Onclick check id or tags.

Comment: @sush but there are many view setting unique id to each is difficult right

Comment: yeah.. but there is no other way identify which way view clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Adding and retrieving the tag while click event can help. Here is the code.

For adding tags:

```
 customView1.setTag(someTag);
 customView1.setOnClickListener(myClickListner);
```

For retrieiving:

```
OnClickListener myClickListener = new onClickListener(){
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if(v.getTag() == someTag){
         //do stuff
    }else if(v.getTag() == otherTag){
         //do something else
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your adapter class you need to write like this am sharing the sample code snippet

```
public static class ChatListItemsViewHolder extends
            RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


        public ChatListItemsViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

            v.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                // write your code here

                }
            });

        }
```

let me know if you need more clarity.